# Strange subnav buttons bug

Tags: html

I have this sub navigation bar bug thats kind of hard to explain but basically i have a bar at the top with 5 categories and only one of them has a sub navigation bar.  I have the whole bar set to fill 100% of the screen with each button filling 20% and this works fine for each button except the button with the sub navigation pages on it.  If you open up this html code im sending tou will see what I mean.  I have no clue whats going on here.

ive tried deleting certain parts to see whats causing the problem and ive tried switching the whole nav bar from body to head to see if that did anything and ive played around with the css alot but nothing is working.

Codesnippet:

```css
/* The navigation menu */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

/* Navigation links */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* The subnavigation menu */
.subnav {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Subnav button */
.subnav .subnavbtn {
  font-size: 16px; 
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;

}
.navbar a:hover, .subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  background-color: green;
}

.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;

  background-color: green;
  z-index: 1;
}

.subnav-content a {

  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.subnav-content a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}


.subnav:hover .subnav-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" style="width 100%">
  <a href="HOME.html"style="width:20%">Home</a>
  <a href="ABOUT.html"style="width:20%">About</a> 
  <a href="MEDIA.html"style="width:20%">Media</a>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn" style="width:20%">OtherGames</button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="subHL.html">Half Life</a>
      <a href="subTF2.html">Team Fortress 2</a>
      <a href="subCS.html">Counter strike: Global Offensive</a>
    </div>
  </div>
   <a href="ACCOUNT.html" Style="width:20%">Account</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
 /* The navigation menu */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

/* Navigation links */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* The subnavigation menu */
.subnav {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.subnav-content a{
    padding: 14px 16px;
}
/* Subnav button */
.subnav .subnavbtn {
  font-size: 16px; 
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;

}
.navbar a:hover, .subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  background-color: green;
}

.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;

  background-color: green;
  z-index: 1;
}

.subnav-content a {

  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.subnav-content a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}


.subnav:hover .subnav-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="navbar" style="width 100%">
  <a href="HOME.html"style="width:20%">Home</a>
  <a href="ABOUT.html"style="width:20%">About</a> 
  <a href="MEDIA.html"style="width:20%">Media</a>
  <div class="subnav" style="width:20%">
    <button class="subnavbtn" style="width: 100%">OtherGames</button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="subHL.html">Half Life</a>
      <a href="subTF2.html">Team Fortress 2</a>
      <a href="subCS.html">Counter strike: Global Offensive</a>
    </div>
  </div>
   <a href="ACCOUNT.html" Style="width:20%">Account</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the 20% width off the button and apply it to the `div.subnav` otherwise it will be 20% of 20% which is what you are currently seeing.

```css
/* The navigation menu */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

/* Navigation links */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* The subnavigation menu */
.subnav {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Subnav button */
.subnav .subnavbtn {
  font-size: 16px; 
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;

}
.navbar a:hover, .subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  background-color: green;
}

.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;

  background-color: green;
  z-index: 1;
}

.subnav-content a {

  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.subnav-content a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}


.subnav:hover .subnav-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" style="width 100%">
  <a href="HOME.html"style="width:20%">Home</a>
  <a href="ABOUT.html"style="width:20%">About</a> 
  <a href="MEDIA.html"style="width:20%">Media</a>
  <div class="subnav"style="width:20%">
    <button class="subnavbtn">OtherGames</button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="subHL.html">Half Life</a>
      <a href="subTF2.html">Team Fortress 2</a>
      <a href="subCS.html">Counter strike: Global Offensive</a>
    </div>
  </div>
   <a href="ACCOUNT.html" Style="width:20%">Account</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change width `20% from a link to div.subnav`, apply `width:100% to button` and add this css

```
.navbar * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
/* The navigation menu */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Navigation links */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* The subnavigation menu */
.subnav {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Subnav button */
.subnav .subnavbtn {
  font-size: 16px; 
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  width:100%;

}
.navbar a:hover, .subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  background-color: green;
}

.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;

  background-color: green;
  z-index: 1;
}

.subnav-content a {

  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display:block;
  float:none;
  text-align:left;
}


.subnav-content a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}


.subnav:hover .subnav-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" style="width 100%">
  <a href="HOME.html"style="width:20%">Home</a>
  <a href="ABOUT.html"style="width:20%">About</a> 
  <a href="MEDIA.html"style="width:20%">Media</a>
  <div class="subnav"style="width:20%">
    <button class="subnavbtn">OtherGames</button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="subHL.html">Half Life</a>
      <a href="subTF2.html">Team Fortress 2</a>
      <a href="subCS.html">Counter strike: Global Offensive</a>
    </div>
  </div>
   <a href="ACCOUNT.html" Style="width:20%">Account</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

element `<button class="subnavbtn" style="width:20%">OtherGames</button>` has inline `width 20%` which should be on its parent, and as bonus you should apply, 
`box-sizing: border-box;` to `.navbar a` because otherwise your padding will be added to your widht, with this code, its substracted, which means the elements will have width 20%